# Как поменять раскладку numpad на виндовскую?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ubuntu-unity

Написал такой скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
setxkbmap -option "numpad:microsoft"
```

но при его вызове он **не выполняется**, *почему*?

И еще, **как** добавить выполнение скрипта в автозагрузку?

Comment: Может надо написать что в конечном итоге хочешь получить?

Comment: в запускаемом gnome-ом x-сервере сейчас вообще всё к чертям поломано в подсистеме xkb. то, что у вас переконфигурация xkb не даёт результатов, скорее всего, нормально (если это слово здесь применимо). теоретически, возможно, помогут какие-нибудь изменения в «реестре gnome» (то, что редактируется программами типа *dconf/gconftool*).